# C# to format @Url.Action("DisplayMeeting", "Home", new { meetingId = @item.meetingId, meetingType = @kvp.Key}) in Model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model as below

```
public class Node
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public Guid meetingId { get; set; }
    public Guid meetingType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code for the controller where I am binding the respective value to the model object

```
bootstrapTree.nodes.Add(new Node
{
    text = val.meetingDate != null ? val.meetingDate.Value.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy") : "",
    meetingId = val.meetingId,
    meetingType = val.meetingType,
    href =string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", "/Home/DisplayMeeting?meetingId=", val.meetingId, "&meetingType=", bootstrapTree.text)
});
```

The current code to bind the data to the href is using to string. Now I, want to bind the data to href as

```
@Url.Action("DisplayMeeting", "Home", new { meetingId = @item.meetingId, meetingType = @kvp.Key})`
```

How can I, modify the existing code to @Url.Action() or any other better option do I have to bind to href.

Comment: can't you format that using normal `href HTML Tags`

Comment: You can use Url.Action inside controlller code. Did you try that ?

Comment: `href = Url.Action("DisplayMeeting", "Home" new { meetingId = val.meetingId, meetingType = val.meetingType })`

Answer (score 0):

`UrlHelper` is available in the Controller and View. If you need it in a ViewModel, you can create an UrlHelper from the HttpContext. If you need it in another class, inject it.

```
var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var href = url.Action("DisplayMeeting", "Home" new { meetingId = val.meetingId, meetingType = val.meetingType })
```